# Jsoup transform my javascript string into a single line

Tags: java, javascript, android, jsoup

I am having trouble with the .append function in Jsoup. I am appending my simple Javascript file response string to a Jsoup Element. But after appending my response transforms into a single line which is hurting me a lot.

My string is like this

```
(function () {

var count = 0;
var root = this;
var require = root.require;
//var require = cordova.require;
require.config({

    config: {
        text: { //this hacks the text api to allow cross domain loading of the templates. it is needed only for the packaged applications
            useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
                //console.log("text.useXhr request came from : " + url + ", " + protocol + " and " + hostname);
                return true;
                //return true if you want to allow this url, given that the 
                //text plugin thinks the request is coming from protocol, hostname, port. 
            }
        },
        'is': {
            isBundled: true
        }
    },
    waitSeconds: 45,
    baseUrl: 'scripts/app',
    deps: ["app"],
```

BUt after appending to a Element it will become

```
(function () { var count = 0; var root = this; var require = root.require; //var require = cordova.require; require.config({ config: { text: { //this hacks the text api to allow cross domain loading of the templates. it is needed only for the packaged applications useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) { //console.log(&quot;text.useXhr request came from : &quot; +
```

My Code is for this

```
String temp=script.attr("src");
                    temp=temp.replace("/"+Heirarchy, DomainName+"/"+Heirarchy.toLowerCase());
                    script.attr("src", temp);
                    script.removeAttr("data-main");
                    script.removeAttr("async");
                    String innerHtml="</script>\n<script>\n"+old_configString;
                    script.append(innerHtml);
```

old_configString is my Javascript response String....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [DataNode](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/DataNode.html) for adding scripts or styles.

```
script.after(new DataNode("<script>" + old_configString + "</script>", "http://domain.tld/path"));
```