# Writing JSON using JSOUP

Tags: java, json, jsoup

here is my simple scenario, I need to inject a JSON array inside the  tag of my HTML document.  I have no problem finding the script tag, and using .append() to insert the JSON.

However the problem is that it encodes the JSON and the browser is unable to do anything with it.

So for example if I start with:

"name": "ComponentOne",
    "version": "1.0",
    "homePage": "http://google.com",

After the append, it turns into:

```
\&quot;name\&quot;: \&quot;ComponentOne\&quot;,\n \&quot;version\&quot;:
```

The ampersand and quotes is not being recognized as a valid JSON array.

Is there a safe way for me to write the JSON array?  While it would be super easy to just write it into a separate file, I cannot, it must be part of the same file unfortunately.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DataNode](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/DataNode.html) for adding scripts or styles:

```
DataNode json = new DataNode("var x = { \"foo\" : \"bar\" }", "http://domain.tld/path");
script.appendChild(json);
```

Comment: Although the answer is quite the same [as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23931602) I don't think the question is a duplicate.

Comment: That definitely does the trick, I am blanking out the baseURI, because I am not sure what exactly I should be putting in for JSON.  Would a blank baseURI pose any problems in the future?

Comment: I think you normally use the URL of the parsed document there.